# Exception: pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Error inferring Arrow data type on using pandas_udf array cols in pandas for pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, pyarrow

I am using pandas_udf of type PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP which returns Pandas dataframe containing each column as dtype object ( in actual an array object ) for each column in input pyspark dataframe.

Pyspark input dataframe looks like this:-

```
id |c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
-----------------------
1  |0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
2  |9  | 6  | 8  | 4  |
```

Here is a sample code:-

```
schema = StructType(List(StructField(c1,ArrayType(IntegerType(),true),true),StructField(c2,ArrayType(IntegerType(),true),true),StructField(c3,ArrayType(IntegerType(),true)

@pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def convert_to_array_udf(pdf):
 //logic to convert scalar value to array as illustrated above
 print(outputdf.head(2)
 print(outputdf.dtypes)
 return outputdf


pyspark_output_df = input_df.groupyby("id").apply(convert_to_array_udf)
```

output of the execution is:-

```
c1     | c2     | c3     | c4     |
-----------------------------------
[0,0]  | [1,1]  | [2,2]  | [3,3]  |
[9,9]  | [6,6]  | [8,8]  | [4,4]  |


c1          object
c2          object
c3          object
dtype: object

File "project\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 253, in create_array
    return pa.Array.from_pandas(s, mask=mask, type=t)
  File "array.pxi", line 335, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
  File "array.pxi", line 170, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "array.pxi", line 70, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
  File "error.pxi", line 77, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Error inferring Arrow data type for collection of Python objects. Got Python object of type int64 but can only handle these types: bool, float, integer, date, datetime, bytes, unicode

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I am using python 3.6.8, pyspark 2.4.3, pyarrow 5.0.0 (although also tested in pyarrow 0.8.0) and pandas 1.1.5.
Does pyarrow not support arrays as of now?

Comment: Hi, as you can see in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html), Pandas UDFs do not support `ArrayType`, `TimestampType` and nested `StructType` yet